# How do I reboot a Vagrant guest from a provisioner?

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, vagrant

Relative newcomer to Vagrant here, trying to eliminate going through the install process manually every time I want to spin up a new Ubuntu VM.

My usual process, after completing the install, is to update all of the machine's software with `apt-get update` and `apt-get dist-upgrade -y`, then rebooting it to ensure all the upgrades take effect. To that end, I made a Vagrantfile like so:

```ruby
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"
  config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    vb.memory = "4096"
  end

  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
    apt-get update
    apt-get dist-upgrade -y
    shutdown -r now
  SHELL
end
```

This mostly does the job — I can see the output from the VM as the packages update — but after it reboots and I `vagrant ssh` into it, none of my files appear in `/vagrant`. I'm assuming the shared folder isn't being remounted for some reason.

My questions are:

- Does it make sense to update the system like this as part of a shell provisioner?
- And if so, how can I reboot the guest and still have the `/vagrant` share mounted?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is exactly what the [vagrant-reload](https://github.com/aidanns/vagrant-reload) plugin is for. After installing it simply add `config.vm.provision :reload` at the point in the provisioning you want to reload.

Answer (score 8):

If you only want to reboot after provisioning is complete (not between provisioning steps), you can use a trigger to achieve this:

```ruby
config.trigger.after [:provision] do |t|
  t.name = "Reboot after provisioning"
  t.run = { :inline => "vagrant reload" }
end
```

This has the advantage of not requiring a plugin to be installed.

More information on triggers [here](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/triggers/).

Comment: This has a major limitation: such trigger will only be run after `vagrant provision` command completes. It will **not** run after the first `vagrant up` is done provisioning. (see: https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/10480)

Comment: It seems as though you can have triggers that run for many events as seen here: https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/10480#issuecomment-444232061

E.g.,
config.trigger.after :up, :provision do |t|... etc. I edited the code to reflect that. Let me know if I messed anything up.

Comment: Now that I think of it, you wouldn't want to do the :up. This means that every time you run `vagrant up` it will also reload the machine. It's harmless, but unnecessary.

Comment: This is indeed a very clean approach (not depending on any plugin) after you upgrade kernel or guest additions

Comment: Rather than explicitly reloading, you could possibly check whether the VM actually *needs* a restart and then trigger a reboot/reload. Typically exit code 1603 denotes a reboot is required, and chocolatey has a warning around a reboot being required/requested as well.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming your guest VM can handle it, using the built in
[Shell Provisioner reboot](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/shell#reboot) may be a good choice. More info on that is [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/pull/10532). Look for reboot in [changelog](https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md) for when this feature was added and improved.

Example block:

```
config.vm.provision :shell do |shell|
    shell.privileged = true
    shell.inline = 'echo rebooting'
    shell.reboot = true
end
```

Answer (score 2):

One liner:

```ruby
config.vm.provision "reboot", type: "shell", inline: "", reboot: true
```

This can also be used as "standalone" this way:

```bash
vagrant provision --provision-with reboot
```

or

```bash
vagrant up --provision-with reboot
```

---

If you need to print a specific message:

```bash
config.vm.provision "reboot", type: "shell", inline: "echo Rebooting", reboot: true
```

or

```ruby
config.vm.provision "reboot", type: "shell", reboot: true, inline: <<-SHELL
  echo "----------"
  echo "| REBOOT |"
  echo "----------"
SHELL
```

Comment: Also worth noting: https://developer.hashicorp.com/vagrant/docs/provisioning/basic_usage#run-once-always-or-never

Answer (score 0):

This can be done like so:

```ruby
config.vm.provision 'shell', path: 'part1.sh'
config.vm.provision 'shell', reboot: true
config.vm.provision 'shell', path: 'part2.sh'
```

https://developer.hashicorp.com/vagrant/docs/provisioning/shell#reboot

Comment: Vagrant documentation suggests: *The shell provisioner takes various options. One of* `inline` *or* `path` *is required*

Answer (score 0):

I was looking to do something like this also but ONLY after YUM updates that REQUIRED a reboot (such as kernel updates).

I opted for the following which works nicely for me - I assume the same sort of functionality would be available to 'apt' but I'm afraid I don't know what it would look like (in rhel it requires a yum/dnf plugin to be enabled to work).

```
node.vm.provision "update", type: "shell", run: "always" do |update|
  update.inline = "sudo dnf -y update && needs-restarting -r -q || shutdown -r now"
end # node.vm.provision
```